# Can't add onmousedown javascript event to control in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

rbl_attend_mark is a RadioButtonList which seems to contain ListItems

I can successfully set the "title" (hover) and attach a javascript function to the "onclick" event handler, but trying to attach javacript to the "onmousedown" function isn't working;

```
foreach (ListItem li in rbl_attend_mark.Items)
{
    li.Attributes.Add("title", attend.Where(r => r.attend_id == int.Parse(item.Value)).First().attend_desc);
    li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:change_background_colour(this.value, this.id, !this.__chk)");
    li.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "javascript:this.__chk = this.checked");
}
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

*EDIT*
I should explain that it's simply not rendering the onmousedown function;

```
<input id="rbl_attend_mark_4085_0" type="radio" value="1" name="rbl_attend_mark_4085" onclick="javascript:change_background_colour(this.value, this.id, !this.__chk);">
```

Comment: You render result does not have "title". And it has ";". Probably not this code?

Comment: something is automatically adding the `;` terminator. good spot with title, that has actually helped, i can now see C# has rendered it in a parent `<span>` along with the onmousedown function. Bizarre, thanks!

Comment: btw the code of [`AttributeCollection`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/AttributeCollection.cs,2472c982acab1729) does not seem to remove the attributes. It html encodes them though ('>', '"', "&', etc.)

Comment: Have you looked at the console to make sure there are no runtime errors in your JavaScript? It would be helpful to see what the browser is indicating, if anything at all. For the record, I ran a test application locally mimicking your code and have successfully run the code, JavaScript and all.